# Is there any tool to convert Oracle commands to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, oracle

Is there any tool which I can use to convert Oracle commands to mysql commands?

Comment: What commands specifically? There is no universal translator possible as they do different things in fundamentally different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for translating `create table` statements, there's [SQL Fairy](http://sqlfairy.sourceforge.net/)